# Minmax JavaScript algorithm return console error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cost' of undefined

Tags: javascript, lodash, minmax

I am working on Tic Tac Toe game, using JavaScrip. When I call the MinMax function I am getting log sequence of error. Here I am calling minmax function and the values that I assigned is OK according to my knowledge.

`const value = minmax(gridCopy, depth+1, ((player===PLAYER_TOKEN)?COMPUTER_TOKEN:PLAYER_TOKEN));`

I am getting error in console

```
main.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cost' of undefined
    at minmax (main.js:86)
    at minmax (main.js:64)
    at minmax (main.js:64)
    at minmax (main.js:64)
    at minmax (main.js:64)
    at minmax (main.js:64)
    at minmax (main.js:64)
    at minmax (main.js:64)
    at minmax (main.js:64)
    at computerMove (main.js:120)
```

If you want to have look on my complete funtion here is the code.

```
function minmax(newGrid, depth, player) {
      const gameState= gameOver(newGrid);
      if(gameState === false) {
        const values= [];
            for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
              for (var j = 0; j<3;j++){
                const gridCopy = _.cloneDeep(newGrid);
                if (gridCopy[i][j]!=='') continue;
                gridCopy[i][j]=player;
                const value = minmax(gridCopy, depth+1, ((player===PLAYER_TOKEN)?COMPUTER_TOKEN:PLAYER_TOKEN));
                values.push({
                  cost:value,
                cell: {
                  i:i,
                  j:j
                }
              });
              }
            }
            if (player === COMPUTER_TOKEN) {
              const max = _.maxBy(values, (v) => {
                return v.cost;
              });
              if (depth === 0) {
                return max.cell;
              }
              else {
                return max.cost;
              }
            }
            else {
              const min = _.minBy(values, (v) => {
                return v.cost;
              });
              if (depth === 0) {
                return min.cell;
              }
              else {
                return min.cost;
              }

            }

      }else if (gameState === null){
        return 0;
      }
      else if (gameState===PLAYER_TOKEN) {
        return depth - 10;
      }
      else if (gameState===COMPUTER_TOKEN) {
        return 10 - depth;
      }
    }
    function computerMove(){
      return minmax(grid,0,COMPUTER_TOKEN);
    }
```

Here is link to complete project

https://codepen.io/ziaullahzia/full/wqpGxW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what wrong here is your recursive function. You are calling `minmax` nine times and when `depth` finally reaches 8 it should resolve its value but it can't because value is calculated from `values` array which would never be filled. And results with calling *.min/*.max methods with empty `values` array.

The inner most recursive call should resolve its return value from a constant or something else but not with some variable (`values`) which is dependent on the recursive function itself.

So in my opinion lower half of `minmax` function should look something like this. But i don't know your cost? algorithm so just returning 1 as result.

```
               if (player === COMPUTER_TOKEN) {
                    const max = _.maxBy(values, (v) => {
                        return v.cost;
                    });
                    if (depth === 8) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return max.cost;
                    }
                } else {
                    const min = _.minBy(values, (v) => {
                        return v.cost;
                    });
                    if (depth === 8) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return min.cost;
                    }

                }
```

But here is another problem. `minmax` function returns an integer value and
`let value = minmax(gridCopy, depth + 1, ((player === PLAYER_TOKEN) ? COMPUTER_TOKEN : PLAYER_TOKEN));` expects an integer value ok, but
`const move = computerMove();` expects position object but gets an integer.

**EDIT**

Sorry for late reply. I looked again the code and i was wrong.

You are simulating gameover for every iteration in `minmax` function with `const gameState = gameOver();`. But gameOver function uses global `grid` variable which is real current game state. So i changed it with `const gameState = gameOver(newGrid);`. And on box click handled changed `let gameState = gameOver();` to `let gameState = gameOver(grid);` Made other changes for game restart and not allowing to change grid cell if game is over or grid cell is not empty.

Modified code [here](https://codepen.io/alperenc/pen/gxjpde)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response................ I am using computerMove() funtion to call minmax funtion. . if you check the code in codepne ... look like that.................................................................. function computerMove(){
  return minmax(grid,0,COMPUTER_TOKEN);
}

Comment: Yes, Thank you, it is working. I will check in details to learn more.